# Как бы выглядел такой JS код в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как бы выглядел такой JS код в React?
Код реализует переключение между классами.

```js
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так.

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  }

  change = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;

    return (
      <div onClick={this.change} className={isOpen ? "style1" : "style2"}>
        { isOpen ? "open" : "close" }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```